# Execute two different queries and fetch

Tags: php

its possible to execute two different queries in `mysql_query` and fetch the records of these two queries.

Comment: It's worth noting that this functionality was **removed** from the mysql extension in the 3.x-4.x days, after it was found to be a *huge* security risk due to SQL Injection.  If you are using the ancient mysql extension, you should not consider doing this under any circumstances whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query dont support this

u can use

[mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

65536 is used to run multiple query in mysql but i am not sure this will help you or not. but I used this to call procedure in php.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','',false,65536); //65536 is used to fire multiple query.
```